# Bulk insert using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, spring

In my controller I am receiving one request which contains 2 parameters: one is an integer value another is a list.

```
{"store_id":12,"product":[[1,10],[2,20],[3,30]]}
```

And I want to insert like

```
12,1,10
12,2,20
12,3,30
```

I am using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` for db queries. I tried with batchquery but its time consuming. Is there any other way to do in better performance?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate just one SQl insert statement. Like this

```
INSERT INTO MyTable 
( Column1, Column2, Column3 ) 
VALUES
( :Value1_1, :Value1_2, :Value1_3 ), 
( :Value2_1, :Value2_2, :Value2_3 ), 
( :Value3_1, :Value3_2, :Value3_3 ), 
;
```

The `VALUES` section is dynamic to insert as many rows of values as you need. All the parameters can be placed accordingly to be used in the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

I have not tried it with millions of rows but for reasonable amount of rows it should work.